# C Mingw "ld.exe: cannot open output file cipher.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c, mingw

I'll start off by saying that I actually can compile C, at least it does work for a simple "hello world". However, I can't compile the following .c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRINGSIZE 10

int getLastPosition(char word[])
{
    int cont=0;
    while(cont<STRINGSIZE)
    {
        if(word[cont]=='\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    return cont;
}


void cipher(int key, char *firstChar, char *lastChar)
{
    char *currentChar = NULL;

    currentChar = firstChar;
    while(currentChar<lastChar)
    {
        *currentChar += key;
        currentChar++;
    }

    printf("\nThe ciphered word is:  ");

    currentChar = firstChar;
    while(currentChar<lastChar)
    {
        printf("%c", *currentChar);
        currentChar++;
    }

}


int main()
{
    char word[STRINGSIZE];
    char *firstChar = NULL;
    char *lastChar = NULL;
    int key;

    printf("Enter a word to cipher (max 10 chars)> \n");
    scanf("%s",word);

    printf("Choose a number to cipher the word > \n");
    scanf("%d",&key);

    firstChar = &word[0];
    lastChar = firstChar + getLastPosition(word);

    cipher(key, firstChar, lastChar);
}
```

I don't have anti-virus software that blocks the output file.
However, I see from the task manager that cipher.exe does get loaded as a process, but killing the task and re-running the c code won't work for me.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly does "won't work for me" mean? What happens when you run it from `cmd`?

Comment: Are you sure you're successfully killing the process?

Comment: I killed the task from cmd with taskkill /im cipher.exe /f /t command

Comment: If you get a fresh process listing after the kill command can you confirm that it's gone?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, it's gone

Comment: @Botje I've seen in various forums online that killing the task and re-running the code solves the problem for most people, but not me. Running "cipher.exe" as a standalone executable file works, but compiling and running the .c file doesn't.

Comment: Delete the old cipher.exe. If you can't, probably some sort of permissions problem. If you can and the problem goes away, you have a WTF?!?, but at least it's gone. if you can delete cipher.exe and the problem doesn't go away, it might be time to talk with the IT department. Assuming the IT department isn't you.

Answer (score 0):

You should really post the output of the build process.

But from what you're saying it seems you're not able to overwrite the output file.
Basically you need to make sure you can overwrite it:

- Make sure the output file isn't locked or currently running, it's easy to test this by deleting it. If that doesn't work you could try again after a fresh restart.
- Make sure your user has permissions to write the file in that location (check the folder permissions).
- Especially when using certain IDEs or build systems it may be a problem when building in a location that contains special characters (like spaces) or a UNC path (starting with `\\\\`). So avoid special locations and special characters in paths.